# Why might referred users not give a +5 reputation bonus on Area 51?

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, area-51, faq-update-request

On Area51, I've committed to [one particular proposal](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/2148/tex-latex-and-friends) and the website informs me that I've brought in 3 referrals. I can even click on that box and get a list of their names, so I know that's accurate. Now, each referral is supposed to give a +5 reputation bonus, but I've only gained 10 reputation from referrals. This seems slightly mysterious.

My best guess at the reason for this is that one of my referred users has not confirmed an email address, which I'm guessing might be the cause because of the following snippet from the Area 51 FAQ

> Make sure they verify their email address, otherwise their commitment won't count.

Is that the case, or is there something else at work? (Some reputation threshold perhaps?)

Either way, it might be a good idea to mention this in the Area 51 FAQ in the section that talks about reputation. For instance, if it's the email address reason, I'd suggest rewording

> Referred user commits to the proposal +5

to

> Referred user with a confirmed email address commits to the proposal +5

or perhaps adding a footnote "You don't get the reputation bonus unless the user confirms his/her email address" or something like that.

By the way, I searched meta to see if this had already been asked about, but I was slightly surprised not to find anything. My apologies if this is a duplicate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct. You only get +5 reputation once the user has committed to the proposal AND confirmed his or her email address.

We updated the FAQ to include your suggested wording.

Comment: btw, is the +25 for following through working?

Comment: @Juan Manuel That should be working later today. I bookmarked [your question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/57121/following-through-on-proposals-and-reputation) to mark it as status-completed afterward, but it seems you deleted it?

Comment: yes, because it didn't seem to have attracted attention... I undeleted it