# Following through on proposals and reputation

Tags: support, status-completed, reputation, area-51, referrals

I just receive an email thanking me for following through on Gaming, and freeing a commitment slot. (great!)

I was wondering when you should receive the [+25 reputation for referral](http://area51.stackexchange.com/faq)s, I referred a little bit of users and I guess *some* of them followed through also... when do I get the reputation candy I like so much?

*Why* you ask? *What good is reputation on area51* you ask?

I want what I was promised, that's all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The +25 rep boost for having a referred user participate in the beta has been implemented!

@Juan Manuel, of the 15 that were just awarded, you earned 4 of them ...you're tied with Atwood for the most ;)

Comment: Ja! (I just want Gaming SE as much as he wanted his proposal)

Comment: Damn, looks like my referees didn't "follow through" :(